# How do I stop a linked image from flashing on a setInterval page update

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table that has an href link to a picture/media file.  When my page updates the image [media] flashes during the setInterval function.  Everything else is fine.  How would I stop this from happening?

php code

```
<?php

include("../lib/config.php");
$conn=mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass","$dbname");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT name, message, time, media FROM message ORDER BY ID DESC");
    mysqli_close($conn);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['message'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
            //echo "<td>" . $row['media'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"" . $row['media'] . "\" target=\"_blank\" alt=\"Media not available\"> <img src=\"" . $row['media'] . "\" height=\"50\" ></a></td>";                              
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get("../pageLinks/messageOne.php" , function(result){
        $("#testMessageOne").html(result);
        });
     }, 20000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to determine that the image(s) are loaded, prior to insertion to the DOM to prevent the flicker caused as the image(s) being rendered/downloaded by the browser.

Flicker Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v8z5bvL2/

To do this you would need to find the image(s) in your requested content and add a `load` event to trigger the insertion into the DOM once all image(s) have completed loading.

The downside is that the content will not be updated until after the images have finished loading.

Anti-Flicker Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g7m1au40/

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get("../pageLinks/messageOne.php" , function(result){
        var result = $(result);
        var img = result.find('img');
        var imgCount = img.length; //count images in the content
        var imgLoaded = 0;
        img.on('load', function() {
            if (imgCount === 0 || imgLoaded++ === imgCount) {
               //the images have finished loading, display the content.
               $("#testMessageOne").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
}, 20000);
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  I think the issue is our code is looking for an image in a folder.  Where I using a href to an image.   When I try this the table display is empty

Comment: Do you mean the `href` is a php script and not a physical image? It should still trigger the load event on the images, unless one was invalid (not loading) which would cause the load count to fail and not fire the `.html(result);`. Please update your question with a sample of the ajax response data, so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ThomasDegroot  Also please check to ensure there are no Javascript errors occurring. (F12, click console tab, then refresh the page).

Comment: I accepted the answer because you got thinking in a new direction and you pointed me to better way of doing this.  Thanks it helps a lot.

Comment: I have to wait 20 hours to award the bounty I guess.

Comment: @ThomasDegroot No worries, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you see if this fixes your problem?

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get("../pageLinks/messageOne.php" , function(result){
    var $html = $(result);
    $("#testMessageOne").replaceWith($html);
    });
 }, 20000);
```

What it does is parse the html **before** it's appended to the document. The jquery object turns it into valid DOM objects before it's pushed to the page.
This means the page doesn't have to do the html parsing after it's content has been cleared and should be able to update the contents much faster, and hopefully within one frame draw because it's all in one javascript call.

Comment: This displays the table data with no flickering, but new data added in the data base is not displayed.

Comment: please post a functioning example html wrapper and sample data what is returned from the ajax request which needs to replace the current displayed data.

Comment: @ThomasDegroot Thinking the commented issue is due to the `replaceWith`, change it to `html`, since your ajax script does not contain the full table e.g. `<table id="testMessageOne">` is replaced with `<tr>...`